# FTP server build in java but listing it's files

Tags: java, list, ftp

How do I make the files in the server appear in a list and appear a number behind it and press its number and download by inserting its number?

The point is trading files with my self that point I can but listing the files that I have in the directory I cant, I can already download files (thats the main point)

```
int porto = 21;
String IP = "x.x.x.x";

public Client() {
    String destinyfile = "directory";
try {
    Socket MyClient = new Socket(IP, porto);
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(MyClient.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(MyClient.getOutputStream());                        
    System.out.println(input.readUTF());
    String arquivo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Insert the name of the file");
    output.writeUTF(arquivo);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(MyClient.getInputStream());
    String fileName = in.readUTF();

    if(fileName != null){
        long size = in.readLong();
        System.out.println("Processing the file: " + fileName + " - "+ size + " bytes.");
        File file = new File(destinyfile);
        if(file.exists() == false){
            file.mkdir();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(caminhoDestino + fileName);
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        while (true) {
            int len = in.read(buf);
            if (len == -1)
                break;
            fos.write(buf, 0, len);
        }           
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
    System.out.println(input.readUTF());
    MyClient.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
```

---

Server

```
int port = 21;

public Servidor() {
    try {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);


        String caminho = "directory";

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Waiting user.");
            Socket socket = ss.accept();
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


            output.writeUTF("Welcome");             
            String arq = input.readUTF();
            System.out.println("File: " + arq);
            File file = new File(caminho + arq);

            if(file.exists()){

                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("Transfering file: " + file.getName());
                out.writeUTF(file.getName());
                out.writeLong(file.length());
                FileInputStream filein = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] buf = new byte[4096];

                while (true) {
                    int len = filein.read(buf);
                    if (len == -1)
                    break;
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                out.close();
                output.writeUTF("File Sent:");
            }else{
                output.writeUTF("File doesnt exist!");
            }
        ss.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `File` object for the parent directory of the files you want to list, you can call that object's [`listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) to get an array of File objects in that directory.

E.g.

```
File parent = new File("/data/folder/");

for (File child : parent.listFiles()) {
    System.out.println(child.getName());
}
```